# Only one or two processes running in multiprocessing

Tags: python, operating-system, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to use multiprocessing to go through layers of directories and grab the key value from the dictionary in the last directory. The problem is I only see one or two processes running every time (used htop) which is low efficient.

this is how i spawn the processes and the function that i used to grab the data. I'm storing it in a 2d array that will be used to generate a heatmap later

````
    first_ins_index = int(first_ins)
    first_ins_path = os.path.join(ins, first_ins)
    temp_hbond_sum = np.zeros((68, 69))

    second_level_dirs = [d for d in sorted(os.listdir(first_ins_path), key=lambda x: int(x))]

    for second_ins in second_level_dirs:
        print("at first directory: " + first_ins + " second directory: " + second_ins)
        sum_hbond = 0
        second_ins_index = int(second_ins)
        second_ins_path = os.path.join(first_ins_path, second_ins)
        
        for mutants in os.listdir(second_ins_path):
            mutant_path = os.path.join(second_ins_path, mutants)
            with open(mutant_path) as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                sum_hbond += data["hbond_count"]
        temp_hbond_sum[first_ins_index - 1, second_ins_index - 1] = sum_hbond
    return temp_hbond_sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_level_dirs = [d for d in sorted(os.listdir(ins), key=lambda x: int(x))]

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_directory, first_level_dirs)
        for result in results:
            ins_hbond_sum += result```
````